# ElasticSearch querying a different database than my app's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch for my MongoDB-backed Rails 3.2.2 app (through [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire)).

I'm having a very strange issue where ElasticSearch seems to be returning query results from a second MongoDB database instead of the one for this app (as defined in my `config/mongoid.yml` file). This is very bizarre!

When I do `Event.all`, I see all the right events.

However, when I try to do `Event.tire.search("foo")` (or `Event.tire.search('*')` even), it gives me the results from another app's MondoDB database instead!

I would expect Tire to tell ElasticSearch to use this app's database automatically, but failing that, would there be a way to set it explicitly?

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!